# regex not working for ZipCode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" id="MyForm" name="MyForm">
<p id="message"></p>
<table id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="A">
                A</label>
            <input id="A" name="A" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="ZipCode">
                Zip Code</label>
            <input id="ZipCode" name="ZipCode" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="submitButton" class="k-button">Next</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        $('#MyForm').submit();
    });
    $.validator.addMethod(
            'regex',
            function (value, element, regexp) {
                var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            }, "");

            $('#MyForm').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                A:
                {
                    required: false,
                    range: [1, 9999999999]
                }
            },
            messages: {
                A: {
                    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}.")
                }
            }
            ,
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.MyForm').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            }
        });
    $("#ZipCode").rules("add", { regex: "^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|\d{9})$|^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$",
        messages: {
            regex: "Zip code must be a Valid US or CA Zip"
        }
    });
});
```

**Question** : There is some issue with Zip Code. It's always saying. Please enter valid Zip Code. But when i test the regex with s/w it is working fine there...

[image]

### **[JSFiddle - Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rg5/10/)**

Comment: Have you used an alert or log statement to identify the exact string your validation function is receiving?

Comment: Yes. test string passed and received is 12345.

Comment: I ask because I'm wondering if there are leading or trailing "hidden" characters that are coming through and breaking your "^" and "$" portions...  I assume a valid CA zip exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: Can u please check my fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did few changes and working fine now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ZipCode").rules("add",
        { regex: /^(\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|\d{9})$|^([a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\d[a-zA-Z]\d)$/,
        messages: {
            regex: "Zip code must be a Valid US or CA Zip"
        }
    });


    $.validator.addMethod(
        'regex',
        function (value, element, regexp) {
            return regexp.test(value);
    }, "");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Javascript, you must escape all escape characters that are not used by the Javascript itself.  Replace all backslashes with double backslashes within your regex, or (as noted by OP in that answer), denote a regex using forward slashes as boundary characters instead of listing it as a string that javascript will attempt to interpret.  Forward slashes are syntactic sugar for explicitly writing `new Regexp("...");`.

Comment: Not easily from my phone.  You may need to experiment with other characters that might need to be escaped, if just escaping the backslashes didn't work...  What I did is tried just "\\d" after finding that the digit match by itself wasn't working...